# mongoose find collections that does not have a empty array

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose

so for example my mongoose collection looks like this

```js
{
 _id: 1,
 arr: []
},
{
 _id: 2,
 arr: [2]
}
```

I want to get all collections that does not have `arr` as a empty array, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$not: {$size: 0}`

```
db.doc.find({ arr: { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } })
```